# Python extension use C can not work

Tags: python, c

OS：linux 
Python：2.7.6 
I wanna use C to write a Python's extension.
My files:

```
.
├── extest
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── math
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── method.pyi
│       └── method.c
└── setup.py
```

The code in method.c:

```
#include <Python.h>

//C function
int add(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    return arg1 + arg2;
}

long sum(PyObject *list)
{
    long s = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < PyList_Size(list); ++i) {
        PyIntObject *value = (PyIntObject *)PyList_GetItem(list, i);
        Py_INCREF(value);
        s += value->ob_ival;
        Py_DECREF(value);
    }
    return s;
}

//add wrapped function
static PyObject* wrap_add(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    //Convert the python input objects into C objects
    int arg1, arg2;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &arg1, &arg2))
        return NULL;
    //Call c function
    int result = add(arg1,arg2);
    //wrap the result from c function to python object.
    return (PyObject*)Py_BuildValue("i", result);
}

static  PyObject *wrap_sum_list(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *num_list;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &num_list))
        return NULL;
    //Call c function
    long result = sum(num_list);
    //wrap the result from c function to python object.
    return Py_BuildValue("i", result);
}

//define the PyMethodDef methods
static PyMethodDef wrap_methods[] = {
        {"add", wrap_add, METH_VARARGS},
        {"sum_list", wrap_sum_list, METH_VARARGS},
        {NULL, NULL}
};


//initilization function
PyMODINIT_FUNC initmethod(void)
{
    Py_InitModule("method", wrap_methods);
}
```

The code in setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.core import Extension
MOD = 'extest'
setup(
    name=MOD,
    packages=["extest.math"],
    zip_safe=False,
    ext_modules=[
        Extension("extest.math.method", sources=['extest/math/method.c']),
    ]
)
```

The code in method.pyi:

```
def add(arg1: int, arg2: int) -> int: ...
def sum_list(num_list: list) -> int: ...
```

I run `python setup.py install`, I seen setup successfully.
But when I type `from extest.math import method` in python console,
it show me that `no module named method`.
I learn how to use C to write Python extension in python.org.
I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Look in _Python_'s _site-packages_ folder (typically _/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages_) in _extest_ folder, there you should have a _math_ folder and inside that one there should be an _method.so_ file. If something from above is not there, then you didn't build the extension correctly.

Comment: @CristiFati: most likely the `__init__.py` files in `exttest` and `extest/math` are missing.

Comment: @CristiFati, there is a folder name extest in site-packages, and there is folder named math in extest, and file method.so in math. all the __init__.py 
files are in their directory.